SSO with Keycloak is not redirecting to the main view
I am working on an app that has just one page. Once the user login, on to the same page, he sees the app.
I have a login with username and password that works well. It means that after login the user is redirected to the app.
I was trying to add a SSO with Keycloak, but after the user login, is redirected again to login.
This is the code:
...
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID

# Dummy user database
USER_DB = {
    "admin": {"password": "admin_password", "role": "admin"},
    "user": {"password": "user_password", "role": "user"}
}


# Configure Keycloak
keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url="http://localhost:8081",
    client_id="bot-app",
    realm_name="my-bot",
    client_secret_key="XXXX"  # Keycloak client secret
)

def login_with_sso():
    auth_url = keycloak_openid.auth_url(redirect_uri="http://localhost:8501")
    st.markdown(f"[Login with SSO]({auth_url})")

    query_params = st.query_params
    if "code" in query_params:
        token = keycloak_openid.token(
            grant_type="authorization_code",
            code=query_params["code"],
            redirect_uri="http://localhost:8501"
        )
        user_info = keycloak_openid.userinfo(token["access_token"])
        st.session_state["logged_in"] = True
        st.session_state["username"] = user_info["preferred_username"]
        st.session_state["access_token"] = token["access_token"]

        # Redirect to Google after login
        st.experimental_rerun()

def login():
    st.title("Login")
    choice = st.selectbox("Choose your login method:", ("Username and password", "SSO"))

    if choice == "Username and password":
        username = st.text_input("Username")
        password = st.text_input("Password", type="password")
        if st.button("Login"):
            user = USER_DB.get(username)
            if user and user["password"] == password:
                st.session_state["logged_in"] = True
                st.session_state["username"] = username
                st.session_state["role"] = user["role"]
            else:
                st.error("Invalid username or password")
    elif choice == "SSO":
        if st.session_state.get("logged_in"):
            st.write("Already logged in as ", st.session_state["username"])
        else:
            login_with_sso()


def chat_bot(controller1):
    # Initialize variables
    if "messages" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.messages = [] 
    if "first_conversation" not in st.session_state:

...

def main():
 if "logged_in" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state["logged_in"] = False

    if not st.session_state["logged_in"]:
        st.image(logo_path, width=150)
        login()
    
    else:
        #st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
        st.title("Test Automation Tool")
        controller1 = Controller()

        with st.sidebar:
            st.image(logo_path, width=150)
            selected = option_menu(
                menu_title="Menu",
                options=["Chat Bot", "Handle Test Cases and Code", "Test Cases Table"],
                icons=["robot", "floppy2", "table"],
                menu_icon="list"
            )

        if selected == "Chat Bot":
            chat_bot(controller1)
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I am not sure if it is an error in the code or if I should change something in the Keycloak configuration.
